# Popup of Word Document and Process JSP page within same HTTP GET Request

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat7

I have an interesting problem.  When the user clicks on a button, I need two things to happen:

1. Pop up a word document
2. Display a *.jsp page that states some sort of message.

The issue is, to generate the word document popup, I have the following in the Controller method:

```
response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + templateTitle);
OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
InputStream inputStream = session.getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/resources/files/" + firm.getFolder() + "/" + templateTitle);

if (inputStream != null) {
    byte[] wordDoc = readFully(inputStream);

    out.write(wordDoc);
    out.flush();
}
```

This works, however, the *.jsp thank you page is not displayed.  If I comment out this code, the *.jsp thank you page is displayed.

My assumption is that I am altering the response attributes which causes the *.jsp not to display.

How can I handle both processes?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to do the impossible. You can't have two responses to a single request.

Comment: I realize that, so I was looking at alternatives and the answer is response.sendRedirect("thank_you"); which will send it to the page I need.

Comment: I meant to say, I thought the answer was response.sendRedirect() but that seems to break the pop-up so I am still investigating alternatives.

Comment: The closest you'll get is display the JSP and then use script inside the JSP to request the word doc. That way you'll have two requests and two responses.